# Received invalid response from the daemon: '...' is a result of a type we don't have a strategy to handle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

### I am getting this error in Android Studio 2.2.3.

this is the message:-

> Gradle '...' project refresh failed

```
Error:Received invalid response from the daemon: 'org. gradle .launcher. daemon. protocol. Forward Input @ 69 ac 64' is a result of a type we don't have a strategy to handle. Earlier, 'Build{id=4....1, current Dir=C:\Users\Hp\A}' request was sent to the daemon. Diagnostics:
No diagnostics available.
```

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the file 'registry.bin.lock' under the location '.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\' resolved the issue for me without having to have restart intelliJ or system.

I didn't want to delete the whole .gradle folder since it takes more time to download all required the gradle files for my big project :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the `.gradle` folder from your project repository and rebuild the project again. Hopefully your problem is resolved. If not completely close the project and open it again. Your problem is resolved.